# KeyCloack Account Management - GET keycloack.js http code 500

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to get started with Keycloack. I have been done basic setup (create realm, create user). Then i open KeyCloack Account Management page
http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/account/

Got an error in network tab for the file request

```
GET
    
scheme
    http
host
    localhost:8080
filename
    /js/keycloak.js
```

`500 Internal Server Error`

Keycloack installed local on my MAC, there are no docker or any additional webserver run.

I cant find anything useful information anywhere. There are some info at keycloack forum, about not correct url of file - it means use /auth/js/keycloak.js instead, but this returns 404.

Comment: I found error in keycloack log
 ./../data/tmp/kc-gzip-cache/.DS_Store is not a directory

So, it seems VS CODE, create this file, and keycloack can not work with path to js file correctly.

I have deleted it, and it works OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found error in keycloack log ./../data/tmp/kc-gzip-cache/.DS_Store is not a directory So, it seems VS CODE, create this file, and keycloack can not work with path to js file correctly. I have deleted it, and it works OK

Comment: It's not VS CODE but macOs Finder that create this file to store view options